# Recyclerview disappears after back to activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is an activity called `HistoryOrdersActivity`. Its layout is as simple as you could imagine,just with a `Recyclerview` inside. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/orders_swipe">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/history_order_recyclerview"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Full code:

```
public class HistoryOrdersActivity extends BaseActivity implements IHistoryOrdersView,SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    private ILocalDishRepository localDishRepository;
    private IGetHistoryOrdersPresenter presenter;
    private RecyclerView historyOrders;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private HistoryOrderAdapter adapter;
    private static final String TAG=HistoryOrdersActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected int setLayoutResourceID() {
        return R.layout.activity_history_orders;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUpView() {
        swipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.orders_swipe);
        historyOrders=$(R.id.history_order_recyclerview);
        historyOrders.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
    @Override
    public void setUpData(){
        localDishRepository=new LocalDishRepositoryImpl();
        presenter=GetHistoryOrdersPresenterImpl.getSingletonInstance(this);
        presenter.getHistoryOrdersByUserId(12);
    }


    @Override
    public void setUpOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        if(adapter==null){
            adapter=new HistoryOrderAdapter(orders,localDishRepository);
            historyOrders.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else adapter.setOrderList(orders);
    }

    @Override
    public void showLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideLoading() {
        if(swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
            Log.i(TAG,"swipe is refreshing");
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
        ToastUtils.getInstance().makeToast("Orders fetched!");

    }

    @Override
    public void showError(String errorMsg) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        presenter.getHistoryOrdersByUserId(12);
        //swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }


}
```

Thiss is presenter:

```
public class GetHistoryOrdersPresenterImpl implements IGetHistoryOrdersPresenter {
    private IRemoteOrderRepository remoteOrderRepository;
    private IHistoryOrdersView historyOrdersView;
    private Handler handler;
    private static GetHistoryOrdersPresenterImpl INSTANCE;

    private GetHistoryOrdersPresenterImpl(IHistoryOrdersView v){
        this.historyOrdersView=v;
        handler= new Handler(GluttonApplication.getInstance().getMainLooper());
        remoteOrderRepository=RemoteOrderRepository.getSingletonInstance(this);
    }

    public  static IGetHistoryOrdersPresenter getSingletonInstance(IHistoryOrdersView v){
        if(INSTANCE==null){
            INSTANCE=new GetHistoryOrdersPresenterImpl(v);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    @Override
    public void getHistoryOrdersByUserId(long userId) {
        handler.post(()->{
          historyOrdersView.showLoading();  
        });
        remoteOrderRepository.getHistoryOrdersByUserId(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public void getHistoryOrdersByUserIdSuccess(List<Order> ordersList) {
        handler.post(()->{
            historyOrdersView.hideLoading();
            historyOrdersView.setUpOrders(ordersList);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void getHistoryOrdersByUserIdFail(String msg) {
        handler.post(()->{
            historyOrdersView.hideLoading();
            historyOrdersView.showError(msg);
        });
    }
}
```

This is adapter:

```
 public class HistoryOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryOrderAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<Order> orderList;
        private ILocalDishRepository repository;
        public HistoryOrderAdapter(List<Order> orders, ILocalDishRepository repository){
            this.orderList=orders;
            this.repository=repository;
        }
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v= LayoutInflater.from(GluttonApplication.getInstance())
                    .inflate(R.layout.history_order_item,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        public void setOrderList(List<Order> orderList){
            this.orderList=orderList;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Order order=orderList.get(position);
            Map<Long,Integer> dishes=order.getDishes();
            List<String>names=dishes.keySet().stream()
                    .map((id)->repository.getName(id))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<Integer> nums=dishes.values().stream().
                    collect(Collectors.toList());
            String time=order.getTime();
            long id=order.getId();
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++){
                builder.append(names.get(i)+"*"+Long.toString(nums.get(i))+"\n");
            }
            holder.dishes.setText(builder.toString());
            holder.id.setText(Long.toString(id));
            holder.time.setText(time);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return orderList.size();
        }
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            private TextView time,id,dishes;
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                time=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.history_order_item_time);
                id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.history_order_item_id);
                dishes=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.history_order_item_dishs);
            }
        }
    }
```

In `setOrderList`,I do call `notifyDataSetChanged` and yes it works:

Screenshot:

[image: It works]

Then I press back and jump to another activity.When I come back to `HistoryOrdersActivity`.All view gone. But I can still get data(I log all data when data comes and a toast will show when the activity gets data).
But nothing shows except for the toast.

Screenshot:

[image: Nothing shows]

Could someone help me? I have worked over this for nearly an hour.

Comment: post whole code here

Comment: @吴环宇: When you are calling `setUpOrders`? `onCreate()` or `onResume()` ?

Comment: @AndiGeeky `setUpOrders` is called through interface callback. It is called from `getHistoryOrdersByUserIdSuccess` in `GetHistoryOrdersByUserIdImpl`

Comment: @BhavinPatel whole code just posted.Thank you

Comment: It seems you have no code in onResume to load the data for the adapter

Comment: U need to refresh your adapter inside `onResume`

Comment: I would simply loadDataFromDB(); setupAdapter(); inside onResume.

Comment: @VygintasB Now I add the code in `onResume` : `presenter.getHistoryOrdersByUserId`  which will finally call `setAdapter`. But this not gonna work.

Comment: @Eenvincible I just want to try MVP structure in my demo. `setAdapter` is called from interface callback

Comment: @VygintasB      Log shows:`E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` Maybe caused by this. But when first come to this activity, the error shows while everything is ok,recyclerview shows

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `OnResume`.

paste following code in your activity which contains Recycler view

```
  @Override
  public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```